# How to store the image in database and shows in listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I want to store some images on a database, recover them later and show them on a custom `ListView`. How can I do that?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
//here, we are making a folder named picFolder to store pics taken by the camera using this application
dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath() + "/picFolder/"; 
    File newdir = new File(dir); 
    if(!newdir.exists()){
        newdir.mkdirs();
    }


//Switch cases are
```

case R.id.btnPhotoGallary2:

```
        Intent gallaryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallaryIntent , TAKE_GALLARY_CODE);//one can be replced with any action code
        break;

    case R.id.btnPhotoCamera1:
        count++;
        String file = dir+count+".jpg";
        File newfile = new File(file);
        try {
            newfile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        capturedPhotoUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedPhotoUri);

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_CAMERA_CODE);
        break;
```

//  Set Photo to Button/ImageView

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0://Captured photo from Camera
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            String pathNamePhoto = capturedPhotoUri.getPath().toString();
            System.out.println("Photo Path Is :"+pathNamePhoto);
            d = BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(pathNamePhoto);
            ivProfile.setImageDrawable(d);
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
            Log.v("CapturedPhoto PATH ==>> ",pathNamePhoto);
            pd.setProfImagepath(pathNamePhoto);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        break;


    case 1://Select Image from Gallery
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selImageUri = data.getData();
            String pathNameImage = getPath(selImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path Is :"+pathNameImage);

            ivProfile.setImageURI(selImageUri);
            Log.d("GallaryDemo", "Get Pic ");
            Log.v("IMAGE PATH ==>> ",pathNameImage);
            pd.setProfImagepath(pathNameImage);
        }          
        dialog.dismiss();
        break;
    }

}
```

//Get Real Path Of Image

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, my advice for storing images on a database is: **Don't**. 
It's not effective, and it's best to store them using paths. This was discussed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).

But. If you're really into storing that for whatever reason. Try to encode the image as a Base64 `String`, and store it on your DB.

Android has the [`Base64 class`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) for this. Try to use the following snippet to encode:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); // Could be Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG or Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP
byte[] bai = baos.toByteArray();

String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(bai, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Call your method to save this string on the DB here.
```

And you'll have to decode it try the following:

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bm;
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inMutable = true;
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);

// Now do whatever you want with the Bitmap.
```

You can see the docs for the `Bitmap` class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).

Answer (score 0):

1.Convert or encode image to base64 string and store it as a string in database. Decode it again into image when you read from database.
2. Convert image to bytearray and store it in DB.